# Why does redis-py's bgsave() command return False after successful execution?

Tags: python, redis

When I fired redis-py's `bgsave()` command, the return value was `False`, but I'm pretty sure the execution was successful because I've checked with `lastsave()`.

However, if I use `save()` the return value would be `True` after successful execution.

Could anyone please explain what `False` indicates for `bgsave()`? Not sure if it has anything to do with `bgsave()` being executed in the background.

Comment: False indicates that redis-py received something other than "Background saving started" as a response. Try issuing BGSAVE with redis-cli and see what the redis' response is.

Comment: @PavelAnossov Running `BGSAVE` in redis-cli gives "Background saving started" correctly.

Comment: Then edit your `redis/client.py`, add `print response` after `response = connection.read_response()` in the `parse_response` method (line 372). While you're there, take a look at the RESPONSE_CALLBACKS dictionary (line 221). See if it does expect "Background saving started" in response to bgsave. If not, then your redis and redis-py versions are mismatched.

Comment: @PavelAnossov This is so weird. In `parse_response`, `print(response)` indeed gives "Background saving started", and the RESPONSE_CALLBACKS dictionary does expect that for bgsave. And yet it still returns `False`.

Comment: Looks like the lambda should read `nativestr(r) == 'Background saving started'` and you found a bug in redis-py.

Comment: @PavelAnossov yep~ you're fast! I was just sending a pull request on github. Thanks a lot for pointing me to the code of client.py. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Pavel Anossov, after reading the code of client.py, I found out that responses from 2 commands (BGSAVE and BGREWRITEAOF) were not converted from bytes to str, and this caused the problem in Python 3.

To fix this issue, just change `lambda r: r ==` to `lambda r: nativestr(r) ==` for these two commands in `RESPONSE_CALLBACKS`.